# ASP page does not load correctly

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a problem with an old asp project. The web interface does not load correctly it somehow chops of the beginning of the page (It deletes the beginning of the HTML page including HTML tags such as HTML, BODY, HEAD and so on also some of the data. The SQL procedure that is responsible for displaying the data set returns the data just fine.

Are there some cache limitations or response time limitations that could be the cause of this problem?  The thing is t that the web page worked perfectly fine when there was much less rows of data in a database that had to be returned now there is more data and the problem has occurred..
[Picture of the problem HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvfoi.png)

Here is the code for the page that is displayed

Thank you for your responses in advance!

```
    <%@ Language=VBScript CODEPAGE=1257%>
<%
Dim page_name           
page_name = "users"

Dim loginas
Dim mod_id
Dim mod_type
Dim usr_type
Dim user_grouping
Dim rkt


If Trim(Request.Form("loginas")) <> "" Then
    loginas = Request.Form("loginas")
Else
    loginas = ""
End If

If Trim(Request.Form("usr_type")) <> "" Then
    usr_type = Request.Form("usr_type")
Else
    usr_type = ""
End If

If Trim(Request.Form("mod_id")) <> "" Then
    mod_id = Request.Form("mod_id")
Else
    mod_id = ""
End If

If Trim(Request.Form("mod_type")) <> "" Then
    mod_type = Request.Form("mod_type")
Else
    mod_type = ""
End If

If Trim(Request.Form("user_grouping")) <> "" Then
    user_grouping = Request.Form("user_grouping")
Else
    user_grouping = ""
End If

If Trim(Request.Form("rkt")) <> "" Then
    rkt = Request.Form("rkt")
Else
    rkt = "0"
End If
%>

<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1257" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>.</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/programs_style.css">
<script LANGUAGE="javascript" src="scripts/programs_script.js"></script>

</head>

<%  If Session.Contents.Count < 1 Then  %>
<body bgcolor="#aabbd7" language="javascript" onload="return Perkrauti()">
<%  Else    %>
<body bgcolor="#aabbd7">

<!--#INCLUDE FILE="inc_sql_sel.asp"-->
<!--#INCLUDE FILE="inc_konstantos.asp"-->

<!--#INCLUDE FILE="inc_head.asp"-->

    <table width="98%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
     <tr>
      <td valign="top" width="190">

    <br>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">

<!--#INCLUDE FILE="inc_user_search.asp"-->

    </table>
    <br>

      </td>
      <td valign="top" class="Table_text-b">

        <br>
<%  Call user_Open()    %>
<!--#INCLUDE FILE="inc_user_list.asp"-->
<%  Call user_Close() %>
<%  Call Conn_Close() %>

        <br>&nbsp;

      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>

  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="Simple_text" colspan="5">
    <%=prg_footer%>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<%  End If  %>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like your CSS is not working, and your table's are not behaving like tables.

Comment: Look at your screenshot, the first line is CSS. That shouldn't be there.

Comment: But this page worked perfectly fine when database returned fewer rows.. It somehow chops the beginning of the data and returns only partial information because SQL database returns around ~ 160k rows this page does not return all the information that the SQL provides

Comment: Also if i hit refresh i sometimes get this line of CSS and sometimes not. Sometimes i get plain data (But not in a table order, just like i provided in a screenshot) and i don't know where the problem is.

Comment: I am confused... You're opening a `table` twice, and you're closing it four times?

Comment: I am not the author for this project :) I am the one that is available at the moment and has to fix it. 

So you think that the problem is in HTML itself?

Comment: I do, HTML is easy on markup but when you close an element twice it will trash your whole page

Comment: Try to remove the 2nd and the 4th close of your table `</td>
 </tr>
</table>`

Comment: The problem remains. It did not help

Comment: Then I cannot help, sorry!